# How to redirect to the another activity when progress dialog dismiss in android

Tags: android

i am new in android development and i have one problem with redirect the activity when the progress dialog dismiss.

I am creating application with help of progress dialog box.i want to redirect the activity when the progress bar dismiss at that time i want to redirect another activity.i search many but i cant get the proper ways.

so please provide me any example,or any sample code so that i can get my requirement.

Comment: What code do you have so far this will help people help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set [onDismissListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setOnDismissListener%28android.content.DialogInterface.OnDismissListener%29) for your progressDialog. and in the `onDismiss()` method invoke your other activity